# Transform light worldspace coordinates to eyespace coordinates

Tags: c++, glsl

I am attempting to model a spotlight in a scene for an introduction to graphics class. The assignment specifies that I must do everything in modernGL, therefore I can't use anything from legacy.

I have been reading the OpenGL 4.0 Shading Language Cookbook for assistance with this, but I can't figure out how to get the eyespace coordinates for my lights. I know the position and direction that I want the lights to be in in worldspace and I have attempted to transform them to eyespace by the following.

```
//mv = inverse(mv);
vec3 light = vec3(vec4(0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 1.0) * mv);
vec3 direction = vec3(vec4(0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0) * mv);
```

Where mv is my modelview matrix generated by

```
glm::mat4 modelview_matrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(window.camera.x, window.camera.y, window.camera.z), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```

without any transforms on it. As you can see I have attempted to multiply by the inverse of the modelview and the modelview to get the eyespace. I am positive that neither of these have worked as the specular highlight on my object follows as I move to the opposite side of the object. (ie if I am looking at the opposite side of the object that the light I shouldn't see a specular highlight.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that you want:

```
vec3 light = vec3(mv * vec4(0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 1.0));
vec3 direction = vec3(mv * vec4(0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
                                             // ^ Note the 0 in the w coordinate
```

Where you have *not* inverted your `mv` matrix. Yes, the order of multiplication does matter. The reason you leave a `0` in the `w` coordinate is because you don't want direction vectors to be translated, only scaled or rotated.

Comment: @JohnathonEnder Can I ask why you are trying to convert your light coordinates into eyespace? Also, mind accepting the answer if it helped you?